# AS3 and FMS4: remote sharedobject reading

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-media-server, shared-objects

I can create (AC3 and FMS4) remote sharedObject (but it's not listed on FMS admin panel, either on local server running on winXP Pro). When I trace results I see firstame value "myfirstname":

```
<...>
public var _so:SharedObject;
<...>
_so = SharedObject.getRemote("myRemoteData", nc.uri, false);
_so.connect(nc);
_so.setProperty( "abc", {firstame:"myfirstname", lastname:"myLastname"} );
trace( _so.data.abc["firstame"]);
<...>
```

but when I want to get these values from another swf and browser with the same connection details, I don't receive anything. No ideas about returned errors, but i think it should be o.k., as I use like this to receive _so values:

```
<...>
_so = SharedObject.getRemote("myRemoteData", nc.uri, false);
_so.connect( nc );
l2.text = _so.data.abc["firstame"];
<...>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try getRemote as SO.getRemote("myRemoteData", nc.url, true)...the thrid parameter flags that SO should persistent across FMS application shutdown. You can also verify that the data should get across to the other client if the first client is still connected to FMS.

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the problem but don't know why yet. I was using default live aplication on FMS server which didn't let me save remote SO. When I changed to my own app problem solved.